# System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags PowerShell Enumeration Equivalent GUI use?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, ntfs

> **Note:** This is *not* a duplicate of the question ["System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags Powershell Equivalent GUI use?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/794849/equivalent-gui-use-of-powershell-system-security-accesscontrol-propagationflags)

---

I'm in a strange predicament.  I understand the concept of ACE permissions inheritance in the NTFS file system; and it makes sense to me when I use it in the code; but when it comes the GUI I'm sort of lost:

The [documentation](https://serverfault.com/questions/794849/equivalent-gui-use-of-powershell-system-security-accesscontrol-propagationflags) for the `System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags` enumeration has the following members

- `ContainerInherit`
- `None`
- `ObjectInherit`

Their explanations in the documentation make sense to me, and I have no issue with them; but I don't understand how each of these relate to doing the same thing in the GUI.

Can you please show me that path to replicating each functionality as it relates to the GUI dialogs?

Comment: @Sven This is not a duplicate.  (http://serverfault.com/questions/794849/equivalent-gui-use-of-powershell-system-security-accesscontrol-propagationflags?noredirect=1#comment1005767_794849)

Answer (score 2):

The GUI equivalent would be the choice for "apply onto"

- Files only = object inherit
- Everything else that includes "folder"
  would be variations of "container inherit"
- None would be a new ACL
  set that is not inherited from the parent.

[image]