# System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags Powershell Equivalent GUI use?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, ntfs

> **Note:** This is *not* a duplicate of the question ["System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags PowerShell Enumeration Equivalent GUI use?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/794847/equivalent-gui-use-of-powershell-system-security-accesscontrol-inheritanceflags)

---

I'm in a strange predicament.  I understand the concept of ACE permissions propagation in the NTFS file system; and it makes sense to me when I use it in the code; but when it comes the GUI I'm sort of lost:

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.propagationflags(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags` enumeration has the following members

- `InheritOnly`
- `None`
- `NoPropagateInherit`

Their explanations in the documentation make sense to me, and I have no issue with them; but I don't understand how each of these relate to doing the same thing in the GUI.

Can you please show me that path to replicating each functionality as it relates to the GUI dialogs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options in the advanced dialog are created by combining Propagation and Inheritance flags.

## GUI options

### This folder only

- Propagation: None
- Inheritance: None

### This folder, subfolders and files

- Propagation: None
- Inheritance: ObjectInherit, ContainerInherit

### This folder and subfolders

- Propagation: None
- Inheritance: ContainerInherit

### This folder and files

- Propagation: None
- Inheritance: ObjectInherit

### Sub folders and files only

- Propagation: InheritOnly
- Inheritance: ObjectInherit, ContainerInherit

### Subfolders only

- Propagation: InheritOnly
- Inheritance: ContainerInherit

### Files only

- Propagation: InheritOnly
- Inheritance: ObjectInherit

## NoPropagateInherit

This flag is added by selecting "Only apply these permissions to objects and/or containers within this container". This option can be set for any right but the "This folder only" option. For example, here are two of them:

### Files only

- Propagation: InheritOnly, NoPropagateInherit
- Inheritance: ObjectInherit

### Sub folders and files only

- Propagation: InheritOnly, NoPropagateInherit
- Inheritance: ObjectInherit, ContainerInherit

If you were to apply an access control entry to C:\Something using that flag the right would apply to C:\Something\Else, but it would not be carried down to C:\Something\Else\Entirely.